# How to set Matlab as default app to open .m file

Tags: file-association

I have the matlab file (.m), the matlab app is also in the desktop entry (I mean that I can search in on the desktop by pressing start menu and type "matlab"), however, for default app I can't find matlab, so I don't know how to associate it. I only know in windows are `ftype` and `assoc`.